# Why is animation frame fired so late?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, phaser-framework

**Hello:**

I am trying to get 60fps while making a game in PhaserJs, but finding it to be very difficult to render each frame in 16.6ms.
When I looked at chrome dev tools I saw that (for example) at this frame, the request animation frame fired so late that it only had less than half of 16.6ms to render the frame.

**Why I don't get at least 10-13ms to render the frame?** Is maybe chrome predicting the time it takes for the app to render the frame based on previous frames?

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Full dump [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/timeline-viewer/?loadTimelineFromURL=https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fne26j8v54pcjr/TimelineRawData-20161010T220536.json?dl=0)

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Browser probably handle their FPS in their own way. If you need 60 FPS, make a SVG or CSS animation.

Comment: I should have said I'm using Phaserjs to program a game.. so that's not an option

Comment: @wOxxOm what do you mean by Compositor line (I've checked the raster section and it is empty even though I've enabled the Paint checkbox) ?

Comment: @wOxxOm No more than those 4 sections see: http://imgur.com/a/ovO7e (running Chrome 53 on Win10) :(

Comment: Go to chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments and enable it, restart Chrome, go to devtools, settings, experiments, tap Shift key 6 times, select `Show all events on Timeline`. Now you're set. If you're on Windows it may ask after 5th tap, ignore it (Esc/Cancel)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your intructions ;), the post images are updated to show the new info.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok sorry for that, now I tried to zoom in as much as possible.

Comment: Good, but I still can't figure it out without seeing 5-10 frames at once, preferably with the time scale ruler in view. So far I don't see a problem because the vertical line marks the moment when a frame was ready, and in this particular case it's right after the code completed. You can upload and share the timeline via https://chromedevtools.github.io/timeline-viewer/

Comment: Done, I just wanted to know why is this kind of behaviour happening that most of the frame time is spent idle while failing to render at 60fps, it makes no sense to me ;)